# Howto install auto-cpufreq?

Tags: software-installation, cpufreq

I am trying to install `auto-cpufreq` using this command

```
git clone https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq.git
cd auto-cpufreq && sudo ./auto-cpufreq-installer
```

After installation of `sudo auto-cpufreq --install` I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/auto-cpufreq: line 22: /opt/auto-cpufreq/venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

How to install `auto-cpufreq`?

[image]

Comment: Install the venv support package, then reinstall your app

Comment: Hi - please remember to include the version of Ubuntu that you are using (in the body/as a tag) so folks can better help you.